# How to iterate and Check for existence of files in directories MS-DOS

Tags: scripting, for-loop, dos

I would like to be able to itereate through all files in a directory. For each file I iterate over I would like to check to see if that file exists in another directory. However everything I try fails. As of right now I have the following code.

```
set base1="c:\documents and settings\pp57542\My Documents\Oracle Readings"
set send1="L:\Documents\Expert Book\Expert Book"

title Backup Script for Startup Routine Step 1
FOR /r %base1% %%c in (*.pdf) DO (if not exist %send1%\%%~nc (echo "Did not exist" & @xcopy %%c %send1% /Y /I /S))
pause
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would you believe you were one character off?  `x` in `%%~nxc` stands for the extension (.pdf).

```
FOR /r %base1% %%c in (*.pdf) DO (if not exist %send1%\%%~nxc (echo "Did not exist" & @xcopy %%c %send1% /Y /I /S))
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: Well now I am getting the error

**Invalid number of Parameters**

What does this mean?

Comment: Yes sir, that happens when I run the batch file

Comment: @Craig, My guess is that the one of the files has a space in it.  the `%send1%` variable is in quotes, but the `%%~nxc` part is not, so it looks like this: `"c:\temp\"file.txt` so a file with spaces would look like this: `"c:\temp\"file name.txt`

Comment: That worked great!

`@FOR /r %base1% %%c in (*.pdf) DO (if not exist %send1%\%%~nxc (@xcopy "%%c" %send1% /Y /I /S))`

That was my solution, it was very easy. Thank you for your help!